# setting a value to a specific position in a list in python

Tags: python, list

I realise this code might be an absolute mess but it's all I have at the moment.

What I want to do is the following: I want to loop through a file, compare each sentence to the rest of the sentences in that file and then do that for every sentence.

At the moment, this is working. The issue comes when I try to insert this info into a 2D list, I keep getting an error. I'm assuming it is because I'm not doing the element setting in the list correctly, and while this might be trivial I can't seem to find anyone who has tried to do something similar.

Thanks in advance.

```
 import re
    import math
    from collections import Counter


    #first understadn this code so that we can manipulate it.
    WORD = re.compile(r'\w+')

    def get_cosine(vec1, vec2):
    intersection =  set(vec1.keys()) & set(vec2.keys())
    numerator = sum([vec1[x] * vec2[x] for x in intersection])

    sum1 = sum([vec1[x]**2 for x in vec1.keys()])
    sum2 = sum([vec2[x]**2 for x in vec2.keys()])
    denominator = math.sqrt(sum1) * math.sqrt(sum2)

    if not denominator:
        return 0.0
    else:
        return float(numerator) / denominator

def text_to_vector(text):
    words = WORD.findall(text)
    return Counter(words)

#count the number of tweets set it to a variable and then set it as the length of this or  what ever

Matrix = [[0 for x in range(6)] for y in range(6)] 

#This is where the text comes from
with open("positive copy.txt", "r") as pt:
    lines = pt.readlines()
    for lineA in lines:
        vectorA = text_to_vector(lineA)
        for lineB in lines:
            vectorB = text_to_vector(lineB)
            cosine = get_cosine(vectorA, vectorB)
            print lineA, lineB, "\n Cosine:", cosine, "\n"            
            array[x][y]=cosine(vectorA, vectorB)
            array[y][x]=cosine(vectorA, vectorB)
            x = x+1
            y= y+1
    print Matrix
```

This is the error:

```
File "/Users/lucasbenitez/Desktop/Twitter/Summary/Re-ordering.py", line 39, in <module>
  array[x][y]=cosine(vectorA, vectorB)

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Here a sample of 'positive.txt':

```
Hello my name is jon
Hello everyone I’m named called jon
this has absolutely nothing to do
everyone Im a doctor
hello I don’t even know whats happening
whats  happening is that you not know
```

Comment: What error are you getting, and on what line?

Comment: Please include the full trackback _verbatim_.

Comment: When you call `cosine(vectorA, vectorB)`, `cosine` must be the name of a function. But it's the variable you assigned 3 lines before.

Comment: Could you provide the code to text_to_vector() and get_cosine() and a few lines of "positive copy.txt".  Where are x and y defined? etc...

Comment: Maybe that should just be `array[x][y] = cosine`. And where do you initialize `x` and `y`?

Comment: `if (x, y != None):` also looks wrong. It should be `if x != None and y != None:`

Comment: array must be Matrix no?

Comment: The question has now been edited let me know if you need any more information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not indented properly, btw.

However, in this line:

```
cosine = get_cosine(vectorA, vectorB)
```

You assign a `float` to `cosine`, so that in this line:

```
array[x][y]=cosine(vectorA, vectorB)
```

You get your traceback, because you are trying to call that `float` which you have just assigned. Perhaps this line should be:

```
array[x][y]=get_cosine(vectorA, vectorB)
```

(And the same with the following line)

---

In answer to your *second* question, here, you initialize `Matrix`:

```
Matrix = [[0 for x in range(6)] for y in range(6)]
```

After that, `x`&`y` are both equal to `5`. So after you increment them (to 6) in in your loop, you are then modifying `Matrix[6][6]`, which gives you your `IndexError`.

Comment: Okay, not its running, but only for 2 iterations and then I get this error: File "/Users/lucasbenitez/Desktop/Twitter/Summary/Re-ordering.py", line 39, in <module>
  Matrix[x][y]=get_cosine(vectorA, vectorB)

IndexError: list index out of range              I tried increasing the array length but this is not working...

Comment: So you have a different problem now. Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: Yes, i believe this is due to the fact the list is not correctly set up which is the purpose of my question however you did solve that issue so ill mark the answer as accepted. I could still do with help on this though

Comment: Please see updated answer. Hopefully this helps. If you have any further problems though, please ask a new question.